# Why all the speeds values are 0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefabToRotate;
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public int numberOfObjects = 5;
    [Range(1, 500)]
    public float[] speeds;
    public bool randomNumbersOfObjects = false;
    public bool randomSpeed = false;

    private List<GameObject> instantiatedObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        speeds = new float[numberOfObjects];
        if(randomNumbersOfObjects == true)
        {
            numberOfObjects = Random.Range(1, 100);
        }
        if(randomSpeed == true)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < speeds.Length; i++)
            {
                speeds[i] = Random.Range(1, 500);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(prefabToRotate);
            instantiatedObjects.Add(go);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            instantiatedObjects[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, speeds[i] * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

And how can I get random numbers and random speeds from the Range sliders ? 1, 100 and 1, 500 ? I want also to be able to change this values of the sliders in the Update and it will update in real time while running the game the number of objects and the random speeds.

Comment: To get a random number between 1 and 100, you can use `Random rand = new Random(); ` and   `int r = rand.Next(1, 100);`

Comment: @ES2018 this is about the unitiy platform, it is recommended to use the static Random instance provided by unity.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, thanks, yes I know static is always better for random type. My suggestion was only giving and hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the length of your 'speeds' array to 'numberOfObjects', then you change the value of 'numberOfObjects', but your 'speeds' array still equals the old value of 'numberOfObjects'. Try setting the length of 'speeds' *after* you assign a random value to 'numberOfObjects', like so

```
if (randomNumbersOfObjects == true)
{
    numberOfObjects = Random.Range(1, 100);
}
speeds = new float[numberOfObjects];
```